# LeetCode 49 Group Anagrams

Tags: java

I've been trying to solve this problem from leetcode that says:

Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams together. You can return the answer in any order. An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once.

Here's a solution I came up with:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) 
    {
        List<List<String>> result=new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(String s: strs)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(sortAlphabetically(s))==false)
            {
                map.put(sortAlphabetically(s), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            else
            {
                map.get(sortAlphabetically(s)).add(s);
            }
        }
        for(String key:map.keySet())
        {
            result.add(map.get(key));
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String sortAlphabetically(String s)
    {
        char[] s2=s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(s2);
        return new String(s2);
    }
}
```

But when I try to run it it says that the output is wrong. What can I improve?

Comment: Please provide sample input and output, esp. the test case which fails.

Comment: can you please provide problem link

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
        if(map.containsKey(sortAlphabetically(s))==false)
        {
            map.put(sortAlphabetically(s), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        else
        {
            map.get(sortAlphabetically(s)).add(s);
        }
```

to

```
        if (!map.containsKey(sortAlphabetically(s))) {
            map.put(sortAlphabetically(s), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.get(sortAlphabetically(s)).add(s);
```

You forgot to add the `String` to the `List` of a new key in your `Map`.

P.S., perhaps you should call `sortAlphabetically(s)` just one time, and store the result in a variable. It will improve performance.

```
    String sorted = sortAlphabetically(s);
    if (!map.containsKey(sorted)) {
        map.put(sorted, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(sorted).add(s);
```

Also note that this solution is case sensitive. i.e. "Sad" is not an anagram of "ads".